# Formatting result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to change a string returned from the following format to a date that shows how many months days since the last order was placed from a customer, I have the following code on the page to get the result -

```
<% @lastorder = Order.select("DateCreated").where("customer_id == ?", customer.id).order("Datecreated desc").find(:all, :limit => 1) %>
```

but this then returns the following format -

```
 [#<Order DateCreated: "2013-01-09 00:00:00">]
```

There is probably a better way to do this but I am unaware of it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your query like that :

```
@last_order = Order
  .where(customer_id: customer.id) # No need to use prepared statement here
  .order('DateCreated DESC')
  .pluck('DateCreated')            # Directly select 1 column
  .first()                         # Only select the first record
```

If you want to display the time distance in words, you should use the rails helper : `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@last_order)`

Info: Just discover than `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` is an alias of `time_ago_in_words`, shorter.

Comment: There is one hiccup however - <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@last_order) %> throws an error - can't convert nil into an exact number

Comment: That's when your request returns no result. You need to check whether a result is returned or not before (the customer should have no order)

Comment: Thanks, used - <% if @last_order.present? %><%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@last_order) %><% end %>

Comment: You can do `<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@last_order) if @last_order %>` or `<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@last_order) unless @last_order.nil? %>`